# How long hadoop mapreduce IntWritable range?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, int, range

Hadoop mapreduce is a framework to analyze the big data. So, one of the example to 
analyze big data is counting program. So I want to ask, how long the hadoop IntWritable range (if the data till billion is it proper to use?). And if we want to count, we do the add or count operation with Java Int data type, and how about Java Int data type range? Is that also proper to analyze the big data? (if the data till billion)

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

IntWritable is also having the same range capacity because it uses int type only internally.

If you want to go beyond this limit then go with **LongWritable**.

You can use int, long type for your local variables but you'll have to use *Writable if your counts are moving on network as a practice for hadoop types :-)

Comment: so we can use Hadoop LonWritable like usual we use IntWritable? without any configuration? Thanks a lot....